# Negation of quantificational logic statement help

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

$$\forall x(x<5\Rightarrow \exists y(x+y > 5)) $$
I want to negate this equation, am I thinking correctly?
$$ \exists x(x\geq5 \land\lnot\forall y(x+y \leq5))$$

Comment: No; $\lnot (p \to q)$ is $(p \land \lnot q)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way to do it
$$\neg\forall x(x\lt5\rightarrow \exists y(x+y \gt 5))$$
$$\equiv\neg\forall x(x\ge5\lor\exists y(x+y \gt 5))$$
$$\equiv\exists x(x\lt5\land\neg\exists y(x+y \gt 5))$$
$$\equiv\exists x(x\lt5\land\forall y(x+y \le 5))$$